# Priority queue is not maintaining sorting order

Tags: java, collections

Priority queue is not maintaining sorting order
**Am i implementing Comparable not properly?
Wrong sorting order is coming as output?**

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

    class A implements Comparable 
    {
        int i;
        A(int i)
        {
            this.i =  i;

        }
        public int compareTo(Object obj)
        {
            return i - ((A)obj).i;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return Integer.toString(i);
        }

    }
    class Manager11
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            PriorityQueue pq =  new PriorityQueue();
            pq.add(new A(9));
            pq.add(new A(5));
            pq.add(new A(8));
            pq.add(new A(19));
            pq.add(new A(1));

            System.out.println(pq);
        }
}
```

Output :
[1, 5, 8, 19, 9]

Comment: Only the first entry is sorted. From the javadoc for PriorityQueue ` The Iterator provided in method iterator() and the Spliterator provided in method spliterator() are not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a priority queue, the only guarantee you have is that the **head** is the lowest (or greatest, depending on your comparison). The internal structure is not necessarily a sorted list. Actually, in Java, it's a heap:

> **PriorityQueue**
>
> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap.

However, if you do a loop that `poll()` the first item, then print it, again and again until the priority queue is empty. The elements should be printed from the lowest to the greatest element.

Comment: There is no such guarantee in `PriorityQueue.toString()`: `AbstractCollection.toString` says: "The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator"; and `PriorityQueue` says: "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.". It is merely an implementation detail that the lowest element appears first.

Answer (score 4):

Priory queue does not guarantee the `ordering`. The internal data structure it uses is `Heap`. But whenever you poll it returns the element in its priority order. For example below code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print(pq.poll() + " ,");
}
```

Gives you the output:

```
1 ,5 ,8 ,9 ,19
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not implementing `Comparable` correctly: it is a generic class, so you should specify the type parameters. I imagine you want `Comparable<A>`.

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
  // ...

  @Override public int compare(A other) {
    return i - other.i;  // Cast is no longer required.
  }

  // ...
}
```

This will not change the output of your code, it will just get rid of the casts and warnings.

Additionally, don't compare ints using subtraction, as this doesn't handle overflows: use `Integer.compare`:

```
return Integer.compare(i, other.i);
```